# Will upgrading to Windows Phone 8.1 void my manufacturer's warranty?

Tags: lumia, update, 8.1

I have a Nokia Lumia 520 with Lumia Black OS. I want to upgrade to Windows Phone 8.1 after reading
**[Windows Phone 8.1: The Good, The Bad & The Ugly [Review]](http://readwrite.com/2014/04/14/windows-phone-81-review/)**

But will the upgrade cost me the phone's manufacturer warranty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, installing the developer preview (the only way to get 8.1 at this point in time) will [void your warranty](http://www.theverge.com/2014/4/14/5612322/windows-phone-8-1-download-features). That being said, people don't seem to have major issues so far, and you can probably flash 8.0 back to your phone if something goes wrong (with some effort).

Comment: Going back to a non-preview release is specifically noted as "not supported"

Comment: @RowlandShaw There is no uninstall, but I've read it should be possible to revert using the Nokia Recovery Toolkit (http://www.nokia.com/us-en/support/software-recovery/, http://www.reddit.com/r/windowsphone/comments/22doot/windows_phone_developer_preview_and_you/).

Answer (score 6):

If you are able to do the update via Settings -> Software Update (or something like that) it will not void the warranty, especially not of the manufacture.

Perhaps if you are using the 'Preview for Developers'-application you may want to check it with your telecom provider - which sold you the phone and thus has given you warranty.

Comment: From https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/develop/devpreview: "*After you install a preview update, **you may void any warranty from your mobile operator and OEM.***" So yes, definitely check with your phone manufacturer or carrier.

Comment: If i update to 8.1 and then if the official update releases then will I be granted to update that time?

Comment: @VivekParekh If by "official update" you mean the upcoming Lumia Cyan firmware update, then yes, you should be able to upgrade to it from the 8.1 Dev Preview. At least that was the case with GDR3 and Lumia Black.

Answer (score 0):

you will not void your warranty AS LONG AS the following condition:-

- no one knows you downloaded preview OS (except you, of course...)
- you uninstalled preview program app
- if you want to send your phone to manufacturers, wait until preview OS version has publicly published

Answer (score 0):

It did not void my warranty, I update my phone 2 weeks before I visited a service center for a heating issue. They didn't ask me anything. They just checked and gave me back after an hour.

Answer (score -2):

No, this does not void the warranty. You can use an app called [Warranty Check](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=c227ca55-b4d6-4464-b4e0-a099a2fff99b) from the Store. I just needed to enter my IMEI number. I updated my phone with the 8.1 Preview for Developers, and my phone is still under warranty.

Comment: Checking the phone's IMEI will only tell you whether or not the phone's warranty has expired. It won't tell you if warranty has been (or might be) invalidated for some other reason, such as physical or liquid damage to the phone, or installing an unsupported/preview version of the operating system.